# Oracle Session Numbers Going Crazy - What is the best strategy to over come this issue?

Tags: database, session, jvm

We have a JVM web application which is running on Oracle Application Server and it uses commons-dbcp (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and implicit connection pooling. Our db is Oracle.

Under heavy load oracle session numbers are going crazy and eventually our system guys need to restart our web application servers.

I am not a system guy, I am just a programmer but I just wonder what is the best strategy for caching up this kind of performance problems. We the programmers are using FindBugs for evaluating connection and cursor leaks.

Does migrating to cloud based, high scalable architectures make sense ?

Comment: Besides moving off of Oracle and to something that doesn't...suck?
I think this would be a better ServerFault question.

Comment: The DBCP might be misconfigured and the pool might go crazy. Did you check its configuration? Is there a maximum pool limit set? Is the Oracle Database instance a shared or dedicated server (regarding the PGA)?